# PHP - the browser doesn't display echo'ed values after "require_once" command, why?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I've been following one tutorial where I am building a user registration system using OOP in PHP. I've been digesting the code quite well and learning fast, but encountered one minor (but frustrating) problem.

My web browser doesn't want to display echo'ed values if the echo command follows `require_once` command unless I add an extra `echo '<br'>` before the values that I want to echo. This is how it looks like:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
echo Config::get('mysql/host');
```

This code above WILL NOT echo the last line in the browser.

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
echo '<br>';
echo Config::get('mysql/host');
```

The code above WILL echo the last line in the browser.

Why do I need to add `echo '<br>'` to display?

I will be very grateful for your advice.

Best,
Lucas

The code in core/init.php looks like that:

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'lr'    
),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800   
),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'    
)
);



spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
require_once 'classes/' .$class . '.php';
});

require_once '/../functions/sanitize.php';


echo $config['mysql']['host'];
```

Comment: Do you use output buffering? What code do you have in `core/init.php` ?

Comment: Marcin, I have added the init.php code in the post.

Comment: Tips: 1) Make sure you're configured PHP to display all possible error messages 2) Use your browser's "View Source" menu to inspect your script's *raw* output.

Comment: Is there more to your code than this? e.g. This is really being included on a page with html markup? My guess here is there is and perhaps it's really there but "hidden" because of the rest of your html/css markup and the `br` is block level tag that's pushing it to where you can see it. Do you even see the `echo $config['mysql']['host']` from your `core/init.php` file?

Comment: include and require_once are functions, right? so shouldn't their values be in parenthesis like include('test.php'); ?or am I missing something?

Comment: `include` and `require_once` are language consructs and it's allowed not to use parenthesis.

Comment: This is the source from the browser:


    `/php
    function escape ($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, END_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }127.0.0.1`
So the value (127.0.0.1) is echoed in the source, but it is not visible to the user..

Comment: I found that the problem is in the escape function. When I disable it, everything works just fine. Htmlentities must be doing something bad to the markup. Thank you all for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code and everything works fine. By the way you should consider not using `$GLOBALS` in your code.

Below the full working code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
echo Config::get('mysql/host');
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'lr'    
),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800   
),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'    
)
);



spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
require_once 'classes/' .$class . '.php';
});

require_once '/../functions/sanitize.php';


echo $config['mysql']['host'];
```

**functions/sanitize.php**

```
<?php 

function escape ($string) 
{ 
    return htmlentities($string, END_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
}
```

**classes/Config.php**

```
<?php

class Config {

    static function get($what) {
        $what  = explode ('/', $what);
        echo $GLOBALS['config'][$what[0]][$what[1]];           
    }
}
```

Result of launching `index.php` file in browser is:

> 127.0.0.1127.0.0.1

as expected (127.0.0.1 is being displayed 2 times without space between)

Comment: It must have been a problem with my browser. I appreciate you checking the code.